# Outlook not showing all address on from field

Tags: java, email, outlook, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am sending a email from my java application using java mail api. My application has a wired requirement, email may have multiple senders most of the time. I am able to add multiple addresses to from field/header and is sending without any issues.

```
Address[] fromAddress = new InternetAddress[users.size()];
message.addFrom(fromAddress);
```

But when I look the email in outlook it shows only the first email in the from header and even though it is an internal email it is not resolved to the name. If I look at the header I can see all other email listed, seperated by comma after From:

```
From: "Abc, Xyz" <abc.xyz@abcd.com>, "Afg, Xyz"
<afg.xyz@@abcd.com>, "Abc, Xyv" <abc.xyv@abcd.com>, "Habc,
xyz" <habc.xyz@abcd.com>
```

Any idea why outlook is not showing all addresses on from?

Can I do some settings on outlook to see that or set some header from my java program.

I know/agree this is a wired requirement but my client needs that as a solution to a legal problem

Answer (score 0):

Outlook assumes there is a single sender in the From and Sender MIME headers. That's how it always worked. I do not know of any email clients that support multiple sender addresses in a single email.

Comment: Is there anything I can do from java to get the emails resolved to name in outlook

Comment: In the Form address? No, that's jus how Outlook works.